# Is there anyway to have instances share the same function yet at the same time have private variables?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-5

I have this piece of code:

```
var Human=function(name){
  this._name=name;
};
Human.prototype.Shout=function(){
  alert(this._name);
};

var tom=new Human("tom");
var john=new Human("john");
alert(tom.Shout===john.Shout);
```

Right now ._name is not "private". I want to make ._name "private", but at the same time i do not wish to create additional functions for each instance of Human (in other words tom.Shout Must be === to john.Shout) because creating additional functions for each instance is just well.. unnecessary (ok offtopic - we can debate this on another thread)

My conclusion is that what I'm trying to achieve (having ._name be "private" and at the same time having `tom.Shout===john.Shout`) is impossible.

But I just want to be 200% sure before jumping into any conclusions.

(I welcome any hacks as long as the requirements are met, i.e no creating of additional functions for each instance)

If we have to create additional functions to do scoping that's fine but that number should be a fixed number and that number should not increase with each additional instance of Human.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but running the above code - wrapped in <script/> - in Chrome, Firefox and IE, as well as nodejs (v8) all alert 'true'.

Comment: @Rob Raisch yes it should be 'true' because the functions are the same instance. In other words we only have 1 function that is "shared" by both Humans

Comment: @Pacerier, And since 'this' is a special context created for per instance, all instances would have their own '_name'.

Comment: @Pacerier You severely over estimate how expense it is to create functions (in the browser).

Comment: @Pacerier, Umm... OK, from what I've read in other comments you want to make _name private, rather than "private" which implies something akin to private but not actually? Are you looking for a sure-fire way of making instance variables truly private, in that they cannot be accessed from outside of their instance? If so, there is not. Javascript allows reflection which would "pierce the veil" of true privacy.

Comment: @RobRaisch that's not fully true. JavaScript only allows reflection in older browsers with the `eval` loophole.

Comment: @Raynos, I'd didn't know that. Thanks. Could you link me to something about the "eval loophole"?

Comment: @RobRaisch [article](http://michaux.ca/articles/module-pattern-provides-no-privacy-at-least-not-in-javascript-tm). Basically evaling code in context of a particular function (including access to closures/local variables). Otherwise local variables are "safe"

Comment: @RobRaisch my motive is to make the interface of the class "clean" by not exposing members when its not needed. If this has the effect of making the code secure that's cool, but right now that's not the motive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Your looking for [`@name`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman%3ainstance_variables) which is an instance variable. Pray it's in es.next, but we don't have it yet. Maybe in two years.

If you care about a clean API then here is your solution:

```
function Class(foo) {
    Class.priv(this).foo = foo;
}

Class.priv = (function() {
    var cache = [],
        uid = 1;

    return function(obj) {
        if (!this.__id) {
            this.__id = uid;
            cache[uid++] = {};
        }
        return cache[this.__id];
    };

}());

Class.prototype.bar = function() {
    console.log(Class.priv(this).foo);
}
```

Store all the data in a cache as a function of the constructor. No data is cluttered on the object.

**Original**

However there is no such thing as "private".

All you can do is create a local variable inside a function.

The constructor function

```
var Human = function(name) {
    // local variable.
    var _name = name;
}
```

Has a local variable that **by very definition of being local** is not usable outside of the constructor function.

This means that you cannot access it in external code like the prototype.

What you can do however is make it read only using ES5

```
var Human = function(name) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "name", { value: name });
}
```

If you can truly achieve what your asking, you'd make a huge breakthrough in js. I've attempted to do just that for many hours.

A different pattern would be :

```
var Human = function(name) {
   this.name = name;

   return {
       Shout: this.Shout.bind(this)
   };
}

Human.prototype.Shout = function() {
   console.log(this.name);
}
```

This has the overhead of calling `.bind` and creating a new object for every instance though.

Comment: yea and .bind actually creates a new function each time it is called. I'm actually ok with the overhead of an additional object because it scales pretty well when we compare it with how those additional-functions scale. What I'm trying to say is if Human class has 6 methods, each new instance has the overhead of 1 object and 6 new functions. if Human class has 12 methods, each new instance has the overhead of 1 object (still) but 12 new functions

Comment: @Pacerier your correct, bind does create a new method. You realise that you should not care about the overhead right? Anything less than 10k instances is no problem, anything over 10k requires profiling. Worrying about this is a _micro_ optimisation.

Comment: yep. I'm seeking for better alternatives in case there's one I'm not aware of

Comment: @Pacerier I've implemented an abstraction to clean your objects up. Your data is still stored in an object though. This is your one extra object per object overhead.

Answer (score 1):

how about this ?

```
    var Human = function (name) {
        var _name = name;

        this.getName = function () {
            return _name;
        }
    };
    Human.prototype.Shout = function () {
        alert(this.getName());
    };

    var tom = new Human("tom");
    var john = new Human("john");

    tom.Shout(); // tom
    john.Shout(); // john
    alert(tom.Shout === john.Shout); // true
```

EDIT:
the former creates another function for GET property,
it is not possible without creating additional functions.

Comment: that's creating an additional function for every instance of Human.. violation of the first, last, and only rule

Comment: that's right but it keeps the _name variable private and access restricted to public properties

Comment: i know but the whole reason for this question is to find out if there's any hacks that allow us to **make ._name "private", but at the same time i do not wish to create additional functions for each instance of Human[/quote]**

Comment: plus we managed to make the interface clean (making _name private) at the cost of making it dirty (adding another public member getName) which sort of defeat the purpose, but to be fair i didn't state that this is not allowed in the question

Comment: @Pacerier A pattern I used to make the interface clean is to have one variable `this._ = {}` and have all local variables as `this._.name`. This shows less clutter unless you look in `this._`

Comment: @Raynos that's a pretty gd hack

Answer (score 1):

Did read the question, didn't understand, because `this._name` is just not private, so the question is a bit weird. This is how in [my test](http://jsfiddle.net/t5Mga/) the prototype methods are added once and available to all instances. I repeat: `this._name` is not private here. If you add a local variable, and want to access it via a closure in a prototype method, calling the value of the local variable will result in the same value for all instances.

Anyway, with this constructor function the this._name getter and shout methods are added to the prototype chain once and thereby available for all instances of Human.

```
function Human(name) {
    if (!(this instanceof Human)){
        return new Human(name);
    }
    this._name = name;

    if (!Human.prototype.Name){
         Human.prototype.Name = function(val){
            if (val){
               this._name = val;
               return this;
            }
            return this._name;
          };
          Human.prototype.shout = function(){
              alert(this._name);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kooilnc `alert(tom.shout === john.shout); // false`

Comment: actually when i said **I want to make ._name "private"** i'd thought it be clear that i meant something along the lines of: **Right now ._name is not "private". I want to make ._name "private"**. Anyway I've edited the phrasing of the question in case someone else gets confused