# Instances sharing prototype methods for use with private instance variables

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming, private-members

This [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998460/is-there-anyway-to-have-instances-share-the-same-function-yet-at-the-same-time-ha/5998856) kept bugging me. It's a question that seems to reappear on a regular basis in SO.

Now I've deviced a way to create a constructor function trying to manage that private 'properties' can only be set from the constructors prototype get/set methods, using a private storage. In it's basic form it looks like this:

The basic constructor function:

```
function Human(){
   /** set up a property storage **/   
   var storage = {
      name: { val: name || '-', get:true, set:true }
      ,age: { val: (age || '0'), get:true, set:true }
   };
   function get(){
       if (get.caller !== Human.prototype.get &&
           get.caller !== Human.prototype.set ){ return null }
       return storage;
   }
   this._get = get;
}
```

Adding get/set prototype methods to `Human`

```
Human.prototype = {
     get: function(prop){
        return this._get()[prop];
     }
    ,set: function(prop, val){
       var storage = this._get();
       /** 
              set functionallity, returning 
              the current object after setting
              see jsfiddle link @ the bottom of
              this question
        **/
       return this;
    }
};
// usage
var pete = new Human('Pete',23);
pete.get('name'); //=> 'Pete'
pete.set('name','Pete Justin');
pete.get('name'); => 'Pete Justin'
// but
pete.name; //=> 'undefined'
```

I am really interested in your comments. Maybe I am thinking in a completely wrong direction, maybe you say it's an unnecessary operation, violating the prototypal nature of js, it already has been done (and better) elsewhere, or anything. Please tell me!

What I think of this - well here let's call it - *pattern*: what you loose using it is the ease of simply declaring and getting properties (`this.some = that` etc.), what you win is better encapsulation, privacy of instance variables and some control over the properties you use (not sure if it's the right terminology, but then again in the OOP world it sometimes looks like everyone gives it's own private meaning to terminology).

Anyway, I've cooked a more complete and working `Human` in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/H2fU5/).

- [**edit1**] In response to comment: ditched the immediately invoke function (iif)
- [**edit2**] Less private alternative without `.caller`, but still able to use the private storage: see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/t37fY)
- [**edit3**] Might as well [ditch the prototype](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/TpFat/) too
- [**edit4**] To be complete: here's a genuine [prototypal get/set variant](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/dNXzd/)

Comment: I'm curious about the reason for the immediately invoked function in the constructor. Seems like you can just make `storage` private to the constructor, and then expose the `get` method directly `this._store = {get: get};`. But maybe I'm missing something. Also, I think the days are numbered for the `.caller` property. You get a `TypeError` in `"strict mode";`.

Comment: @patrick: afaik days are numbered for the `arguments.caller`, not for `function.caller`. And yes, `storage` can also be a private variable of the constructor itself, good call. It being in the iif (no, this is not ms-access;) is a remnant of all the fiddling around. No particular reason. The iif could be ditched, as is demonstrated in this fork: http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/H2fU5/

Comment: I hate to say it, but in [15.3.5 Properties of Function Instances](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.3.5) you'll find: *"Function instances that correspond to strict mode functions (13.2) and function instances created using the Function.prototype.bind method (15.3.4.5) have properties named "caller" and "arguments" that throw a TypeError exception. An ECMAScript implementation must not associate any implementation specific behaviour with accesses of these properties from strict mode function code.*

Comment: @patrick: keep calm, I never shoot messengers. And yes, you are right. If you add strict mode to the fiddles I created you can test your being right (righteousness? I'm dutch, sorry) in FF4. For now I'll omit strict mode then. Would you happen to know of a viable alternative for it?

Comment: @KooiInc: I think you're looking for "correctness", *for there are none that are righteous, no, not one*. :o)

Comment: @all: thanks for your contributions. To be complete I've added a link to the genuine getter/setter version of the Human constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all what is this overly engineered solution trying to solve?

The problem with trying to access constructor local variables from the prototype is not a problem. People either need to only use the prototype and store all the data on `this` for a minor speed gain or not complain about creating extra functions for each object (minimal overhead). It's a common misunderstanding that creating extra functions for each object is expensive.

---

No offence but the code is over engineered, complex and seems like a right pain to read or maintain. I don't see any advantages in this method? Why not just make `this._store` a privileged function.

Also the fact that you have a local function in your constructor means you lose that advantage with the prototype of having one function for all objects. I've also over engineered a solution similar to this to "emulate" private variables, the code became a right mess to work with and I had to abandon it.

---

As for code critism:

[`.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) is non standard. You can't use it. It's a hack.

`this._store = {get:get};`

Why not just `this._store = get` ?

This

```
function thisget(prop){
    return storage[prop];
}
return thisget(prop);
```

should be inlined to

`return storage[prop]`

Comment: I'd tend to agree. Even aside from the `caller` issue and the code style issues, if security is the objective, it can be overridden by replacing the `get` and `set` method in `Human.prototype` with your own that calls `this._store.get()`.

Comment: Thanks Raynos. Yep, overly engineered it is. It's more about the idea, the code has to be optimized ofcourse. I'm using non standard but widely use (and usable) `Function.caller`, as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller. If anyone has an alternative, I'd be glad to hear about it.

Comment: @Kooilnc There is no alternative. What your trying to achieve cannot be achieved and does not need to be achieved. All your left with is spaghetti code :)

Comment: @Raynos: I agree on the no need part, really. But the question returns frequently here @ SO, and I wanted to check all possibilities. If so many people are asking to squeeze private (or must I say classical OOP) stuff into the prototypal model, you start to wonder of you're the one that doesn't get it. That may well be te case, I admit.

Comment: @patrick: your *correctness* is overwhelming ;~) See my answer to Raynos' comment. Security is not an (my) issue. What may remain imho for this pattern (I simplified the fiddle by the way) may be the control you have over setting/getting the properties, even if we ditch the `.caller`.

Comment: @KooiInc: I'm by no means a JavaScript guru, but I think I've come to realize that JavaScript is a *"figure out the least egregious pattern that will accomplish what you need"* language. Or to be more concise, *"whatever floats your boat"*. :o)

Comment: @patrick: your correctness takes *egregious* forms, one could say :D Anyway, to keep the boat floating you can get rid of a lot of stuff on it, that's what I've been doing - ditching a lot of stuff, the boat still floats. Note: I don't think the *egregious* thingy applies to js only, having to work with c#, php, perl, sql etc. now and again.

Comment: @KooiInc: I must admit that I'm not terribly familiar with other languages, though I've been itching to spend some time with Erlang. Sounds like you're on the right track with your solution though. I'm definitely in favor of throwing as much overboard as possible. Great design seeks simplicity.